# How to open firewall from terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, firewall

I am developing a go app on a server(mac-mini) where I connect via ssh. I  restart the app many times: `go run main.go`

Problem is, that I dont have access to the graphical ui - "Firewall Options...".

I really like to have the firewall on for security reason and poke minimal holes in it only when needed.

Is there any way to set and allow a port to be open, for incoming connections from the terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Configure the firewall to be permissible for selected applications and services.

   > To turn the firewall on for specific applications/services :
   >
   > ```
   > sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf globalstate -int 1
   > ```

   https://raymii.org/s/snippets/OS_X_-_Turn_firewall_on_or_off_from_the_command_line.html

   Reboot for the change to take effect.
2. `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw` allows you to configure applications through the firewall. The tool provides its own help and documentation.

   For example, to grant an application incoming connections, you can use

   ```
   /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --add "/Applications/Foo.app"
   ```